# jQuery eased animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've my codes as

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
    <div id="four"></div>
</div>
```

Each div has a width of 250px & are floated left;
When I click a button, I'm using hide('one');
When the div#one disappears, the remaining three divs takes it's empty place and it happens all of a sudden. What I want is, when the div#one disappears, I want the remaining 3 divs to slide to the left slowly.. in a eased manner. How should I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just give a duration to [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) you're all set, it'll be an animation, like this:

```
$("#one").hide("slow");
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/xKngP/).
<sub>Note: This works with or without jQuery UI, it's part of jQuery Core</sub>

Comment: @ptamzz - just a tip, you can also pass a number for the duration in milliseconds, here's a slowed down version to show that: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/xKngP/1/

Comment: Actually, I also wanted a slide out effect so that it looks like the div#one slides out and Im using   $('#one').hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 200); as the div slides out, I want the remaining divs to replace it's space.. can you please help me on that?

Comment: @ptamzz - unfortunately, the way it's written you can't do that with the effect, because of how it works, by creating a wrapper.  What you *could* do is `.animate({ width: "toggle" }, 1000);`, check it out here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/xKngP/2/

Answer (score 1):

One way is to shrink that div... but if you want a fadeOut and then a shrink, you can first use animate() to change the opacity to 0, and then shrink that div, using also animate().  You can use a callback with the first animate() or queue the two animations together.

Seems like Nick's answer of hide() will fade and shrink at the same time, which might be all you need.